# Creating an if/elif statement with regex error in python

Tags: python

So recently I started learning python through an online education platform and currently I hit a wall.

So the problem is:

Create an if statement that takes an age value. This if statement should print the word “child” if age is 12 or less, “teenager” if age is between 13 and 19 inclusive, and “adult” if age is greater than 19.

and my code is:

```
age = 16

if age < 13:
    print("child")

elif (age >= 13) and (age < 20):
    print("teenager")

else:
    print("adult")
```

So according to the website, the part I did for child and adult is correct but the teenager part of it is wrong and is showing this regex message:

```
Searched your code for a specific pattern:

^elif (13\s*<=\s*age|12\s*<\s*age)?\s*(or|\|)?\s*(age)?(\s*<\s*20|\s*<=\s*19):$\s*print\(('|")teenager('|")\)
```

So I basically tried learning regex to understand what I did wrong and what I could understand from it is basically but I'm sure that I'm reading it wrong:

```
elif (13 <= age 12 < age) or (age < 20 <= 19):
    print("teenager")
```

So what am I missing? Any help would be very much appreciated thanks! :)

Comment: Looks like an overzealous website trying to parse Python with regex to do some sort of misguided linting. My advice is to find a website that's not garbage. Your code is fine. It works perfectly well.

Comment: first of all you need to improve the if-else statement , `if 19>age>13:` like this

Comment: For the first `elif`, just use `elif age < 20:`  You can only reach that if `age` is `>= 13`, so checking it again is redundant (and apparently isn't one of their accepted patterns).  Simplify it.  Don't repeat work.

Comment: "find a website that's not garbage": this x1000.  Testing your code by trying to parse it instead of just running it is bad enough, doing it via a regex adds another layer of bad, and then on top of that giving you that regex *as the error message* when you're doing a beginner-level coding problem is bad enough to warrant capital punishment.  The fact that fraudsters are allowed to inflict this kind of nonsense on people who are trying to learn something makes me actually angry.

Comment: @Nightwing97 While you were understanding their regex, they meant you can either write (13<=age) or write (12<age) since both are valid, it's not (13 <= age 12 < age).  The same goes for the upper bound condition.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions! I did manage to solve it  thanks to Tom's answer. As to why I'm using that particular website is because it's free and I also get a certificate upon completion so I have something to add to my resume while also learning python.